# Ruby Sinatra create post request

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I created web-application and I have one problem with creating post request to https server.
My code for get request is here:

```
 uri = URI('https://test.com/all')

  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
                  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    request.basic_auth 'dt', 'dt'

    response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

    return response.body
  end
```

How to create POST request?
I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a piece from a google authorisation method which uses post, it can be simpler but so you can see how to use params, ssl etc

```
  require 'net/http'
  require 'net/https'
  require 'uri'

  @title = "Google Authetication"
  token = params[:code]
  client_secret = "***********************"
  uri = URI('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

  request.set_form_data('code' => token, 'client_id' => @client_id, 'client_secret' => client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => googleauth_url, 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code')
  request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  response = http.request(request)
  response.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

Comment: not working `uri = URI.parse('https://test.com/check_account_exists')
  request =  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'username' => username, 'email' => email)
  request.basic_auth 'dt', 'dt'
  return request.body`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, my working code:

```
 uri = URI('https://test.com/olololo')
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
                  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.request_uri
    request.basic_auth 'dt', 'dt'
    request.body = res_Data.to_json
    response = http.request request
    return response.body
    end
```